Postman to Excel Power Query
I am trying to get data into Excel Power Query from an API with API key.
In Postman it works with this:
https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?query=pasta&maxFat=25&number=10
x-api-key   28fa216f987c42bea1f3xxxxxxxxxxxx
I am trying to use the "Web-API" key but Excel returns "You can only use an internet-API-key when the name on the internet-API-key is delivered" (translated)
How do I get these data into Excel Power Query?

There are two ways to do this according to the Spoonacular API docs.
First use the "From Web" option on the Get & Transform section of the Data tab in Excel. Then you can choose between two options:
Option 1: API key in request header
You can put the api key in the GET request header just as you are currently doing in Postman.
IMPORTANT: Choose Anonymous authentication on the next dialog. Web API authentication is for a different purpose.

Option 2: API key in the URL
For this particular API you can put the api key as a URL parameter. This URL will also just work in a web browser (replace with correct api key)
https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?query=pasta&maxFat=25&number=10&apiKey=28fa216f987c42bea1f3xxxxxxxxxxxx


Great thank you so much to clarify.
